# Conditional class in slim with 3 conditions

Tags: ruby, class, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5, slim-lang

I would like to write conditional class in slim but I only know how to do it with 2 conditions, like :

```
div class=(index == 0 ? 'class1' : 'class1 class3')
```

How to do it with three conditions?

```
- if index == 0
  .class1
- elsif index == -1
  .class2.class3
- else
  .class1.class3
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend putting something like this into a helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div class=(if index == 0 then 'class1' elsif index == -1
then 'class2 class3' else '.class1 class3' end)
```