# How to conditionally wrap or indent in Slim

Tags: slim-lang

There's a significant chance that this question is a duplicate because I don't know how to ask it properly. I'm looking for the best practice to conditionally wrap or indent in [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/).

First, I'll give an example in straight ERB.

```
<% if some_condition? %>
  <a href="#">
<% end %>
    <span>foo</span>
<% if some_condition? %>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

In the case that `condition?` returns truthy you'll get `<a href="#"><span>foo</span></a>`. If not, you'll just get `<span>foo</span>`.

In Slim I'm not sure what the most appropriate way to proceed is.

Maybe assuming that I have a way of rendering partials ...

```
# _span-foo.html.slim
span foo
# view.html.slim
- if some_condition?
  a href="#"
    = partial "_span-foo.html.slim"
- else
  = partial "_span-foo.html.slim"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is probably the best way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, I've run into this problem multiple times while developing in Slim.  It's a consequence of the simpler syntax.  Sometimes while developing we bump into the limits of our tools. There's nothing wrong with acknowledging that a solution that _feels_ non-optimal based on our experiences with other tools is **in fact** optimal.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I am upvoting and accepting the answer. Good etiquette dictates that a downvote is followed up by a detailed comment. Your elaboration in the comment is valuable as part of the answer and I wish you'd move it there.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [Conditional class in slim with 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591084/conditional-class-in-slim-with-3-conditions)

and using @craig-walker answer, You can solve it in one file as

```
# view.html.slim
- span_content = capture do
  span foo

- if some_condition?
  a href="#"
    = span_content
- else
  = span_content
```